# Qt Thread with ping operation in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt

I am trying to accomplish what looks like a very simple task... but it's being a nightmare instead.

I developed an app for a Linux Laptop. Inside the app, I would like to have an independent thread that continuously pings another PC (eg once every 5 seconds, forever... well, as long as the laptop is switched on).

Of course, when the PC that the app is pinging is not connected, the app has to work smoothly, without waiting for the ping operation to return... How can I achieve this?

At first I used a `QTimer` with `QProcess:execute("ping"...)`, which works fine. The problem is that if the other PC doesn't reply, my whole app and its GUI freeze for about one second at each ping operation. Changing the "ping" options (setting "-i0.2", for example), in order to reduce waiting time for the ping operation, didn't help: when the other PC is not connected my app becomes very slow. If I remove the ping, of course everything works smoothly.

So, I decided to insert the "ping" operation in a `QThread`, but when I try to follow the second example in http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html, nothing seems to work: the app doesn't even start.

Here's the code:

```
//Pinger.h
class Pinger : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT  
 void run();
public:
    void setParam(const QString &urlToPing); // it sets the url to ping

signals:
    /// \brief  Signal emitted when pinging of specified url fails
    void pingFailed(int ok);
private:
    QString pingurl;
};

//Pinger.cpp
void Pinger::run()
{
    int exitCode;
    QProcess pingProc;
    while(true)
    {
        exitCode=pingProc.execute("ping",QStringList() << "-c 1" << "-i0.2" << pingurl);
        emit pingFailed(exitCode);
        sleep(5);
    }
}

// MainWindow::MainWindow
        pinga= new Pinger(); // defined in mainwindow.h as Pinger* Pinga
        pinga->setParam(ip_address);
        connect(pinga,SIGNAL(pingFailed(int)),this,SLOT(connectionLost(int)));
        connect(pinga,SIGNAL(finished()),pinga,SLOT(deleteLater()));
        pinga->start();
```

Has anyone tried anything similar? I am quite new to Qt, but this operation seems so trivial that I find it incredible that there's no clear way to implement it. so I hope I am just missing something obvious.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce** it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: While the question itself is very unclear, i wonder, what are the reasons behind choosing QT threads as opposed to standard c++ threads?

Comment: I edited my post and added the code, I had some problem indenting everything and I didn't think you would be so fast! I am using QT for my app so I thought I would use QT for the thread.

Comment: your example is not a complete one, there could be all sorts of errors in code you don't show.

Comment: Use a QProcess instance and call start() instead of execute(). Connect to the error and finished() signals to get the return code. No threads needed then.

Answer (score 2):

If `QThread` is used it is better to avoid `sleep(5);` and the loop `while(true)`, since the thread cannot be closed gracefully without killing it. Instead of the loop and blocking sleep it is better to call that periodic task again by single shot timer initiated when the previous task (process execution) is finished. However, in that case that logic should be implemented in some other member slot (`Pinger::doWork()`). The slot `run()` should be kept with its default implementation that executes the tread event loop. The work can be started by connecting the `QThread::started()` signal with `Pinger::doWork()`:

```
connect(pinga, SIGNAL(started()), pinga, SLOT(doWork()));
```

---

It is needed to be careful with `QThread` deletion. In general it is not good to delete `QThread` object by itself (calling `deleteLater()` from its `finished()` signal). It is better to stop the thread and to delete it in `MainWindow` destructor:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow
{
    // stop the even loop
    pinga->quit();
    // wait for finishing current thread task; it can work only
    // if the thread is not blocked by while(true) with sleep
    pinga->wait();
    // delete if it is not a smart pointer
    delete pinga;
 }
```

---

It is also possible to use `QProcess` with its non-blocking API in the main GUI thread without `QThread`. In that case it should be started by `QProcess::start()` and the slots connected to the signals `QProcess::error()` and `QProcess::finished()` should be used to start the next iteration. Those slots also should not block the main thread, so the next ping should be started using `QTimer` once previous ping is finished.

Comment: This. You do not need threads for something as simple as this. In Qt, if you're using threads for just about anything other than a very processor-intensive computation, You're Doing It Wrong. Just use the non-blocking QProcess API.

Comment: Agree that it is overkill to use `QThread` for such task. It may be useful just for learning `QThread` and also the task may grow in the future. There are two cases when `QThread` is really needed. 1. Some heavy function that cannot be called asynchronously may block the main GUI thread. 2. It is needed to have as much as possible good timing for some worker thread (some streaming) even when GUI thread may be busy, for example due to active moving some window by mouse.

Comment: Thank you @ScottG and thank you all for your help. So my original mistake was to use QProcess::execute instead of QProcess::start... which I haven't managed to make it work.
Now the solution in my original post (with QThread) works fine, but as I understand that it's not the best solution I'll try to make QProcess::start work thanks to the examples you posted.

Comment: Despite of the remarks regarding improvements the original question code should also work. If for some reason it does not work the problem is not revealed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the "Qt Way" to write your Pinger class. Note that no threads are needed. QProcess is used asynchronously, and reports its status through a Qt signal. Once you really grok Qt, you'll realize that using threads is very rarely the right or most natural solution to these types of problems.

Note that I'm using Qt 5 with C++11 support enabled to connect Qt signals to C++11 lambdas... you could just as easily write it in Qt4 style but it wouldn't be as compact and readable.

```
class Pinger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Pinger(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        //Have to do this ugliness because QProcess::finished is overloaded
        auto finishedFunc = static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished);
        connect(&m_process, finishedFunc, [this](int exitCode)
        {
            if( exitCode == 0 )
            {
                emit pingSuccess();
            }
            else
            {
                emit pingFailed(exitCode);
            }
        });
    }

    void run(const QString& hostToPing, int intervalInSeconds)
    {
        m_host = hostToPing;
        QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
        timer->start(intervalInSeconds * 1000);

        QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]()
        {
            if ( m_process.state() == QProcess::NotRunning )
            {
                m_process.start(QString("ping -c 1 -W 1 %1").arg(m_host));
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Cannot ping, previous ping operation still in progress!";
            }
        });
    }

signals:
    void pingSuccess();
    void pingFailed(int exitCode);

private:
    QProcess m_process;
    QString  m_host;
};
```

Using it is as simple as:

```
Pinger pinger;
QObject::connect(&pinger, &Pinger::pingSuccess, []()
{
    qDebug() << "Host is up!";
});

QObject::connect(&pinger, &Pinger::pingFailed, [](int exitCode)
{
    qDebug() << "Host is unreachable! Ping exit code = " << exitCode;
});

pinger.run("google.com", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by running the `ping` command in an own thread. By using a signal, I'm interacting with the non-blocking GUI.

1) I've declared a Ping class, which run the Ping command:

```
class Ping {
   public: 
      static bool start(QString host) {
        QStringList parameters;
        #if defined(WIN32)
           parameters << "-n" << "1";
        #else
           parameters << "-c 1";
        #endif

        parameters << host;

       int exitCode = QProcess::execute("ping", parameters);
       if (exitCode==0) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
};
```

2.) Additionally I've a NetworkReceiver class, which creates the Network Thread via a Slot (`startConnectionCheck`) and interacts with the GUI via a Signal (`newConnectionStatus`):

```
class NetworkReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NetworkReceiver(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    ~NetworkReceiver();

    void start() {
        while(true) {
            emit newConnectionStatus(Ping::start("google.at"));
            QThread::sleep(5);
        }
    }

signals:
    void newConnectionStatus(bool connected);

public slots:
    void startConnectionCheck() {
        QFuture<void> test = QtConcurrent::run(this, &NetworkReceiver::start);
    }

};
```